# Caption package: bold numbering indents caption text - how to avoid that?

Tags: captions, indentation, bold

I ran across this problem and fail to find an answer even after thorough searching:

I use

```
\usepackage[bf]{caption}
```

in my LaTeX document, as I want the "Figure 1"-Part of the caption to appear **bold**. Unfortunately, the following caption is indented starting on the second line, so that the "Figure 1" part is alone:

```
Figure 1: blabla, bla-  
          blablabla
          blabal
          blablabla
```

I'd prefer sth like this (the other variant looks really stupid for narrow floats and wastes space):

```
Figure 1: blabla, bla-
blablabla blabla blabla
```

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744185/latex-caption-package-bold-numbering-indents-caption-text-how-to-avoid-that?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: The caption documentation (available e.g. with `texdoc caption`) has a section on formatting. You should really read it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I looked this up in a far older version of the documentation which didn't list the below-mentioned way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The package `caption` provides different styles via option. To set one of the predefined styles use `format=`.

Here an example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[bf]{caption} 
\def\exampletext{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna.
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\rule{7cm}{1cm}
\caption{\exampletext}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\captionsetup{format=plain}
\centering
\rule{7cm}{1cm}
\caption{\exampletext}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\captionsetup{format=hang}
\centering
\rule{7cm}{1cm}
\caption{\exampletext}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, solves it for my images. Unfortunately, on first glance, this doesn't seem to work with ctable. Let's see if I find a solution for that.

Answer (score 4):

If including the line `\usepackage[bf]{caption}` is causing the captions to be formatted "hanging" while they do not without this line, then this is clearly a bug in my `caption` package. Please give me a Minimal Working Example (MWE) so I can fix this.

Unless this is fixed by me I would avoid usage of my `caption` package since there is a compatibility problem here which influence can't be estimated - it could cause serious other problems.

Comment: Shouldn't this rather be a comment to the OP's question?

Comment: It fails with KOMA classes, probably redefined internally somewhere, but you right a MWE is always a must.

Comment: I just added a solution to my answer (avoiding my `caption` package) - and IMHO this is the right solution, I would clearly not recommended "fixing" this by other `caption` package settings like `format=plain`. At least unless we know what the real problem is.

Comment: Yiannis, what do you mean by "it fails with KOMA classes"?

Comment: Okay, trying to construct an example, I used captions without your package, resulting in hanging captions, too. Is this standart? I must confess, I remember this differently, but if it is, then the problem doesn't lie with your package, obviously.

Comment: Seems I was completely misleaded by your phrase "bold numbering indents caption text". It seems the real answer is simply: No, this is not true, the bold numbering does not indents caption text. (As already stated it would be a bug otherwise.)

Comment: Sorry for that, I had the impression that this issue arose after adding the caption package - my bad. Thank you for providing the package, I really appreciate the help and work that ppl invest into latex and guys like me :)